# Use session parameters set by attached native dll in Exit Dialog of advanced installer

Tags: session, dll, advanced-installer

I need to use session values which are set inside a custom action attached native dll inside Exit Dialog, but I can see only default values of these session parameters in setup.

**Session parameter definition inside advanced installer setup:**
[image: Session parameter definition inside advanced installer setup]

**Session parameter value update inside custom action attached native dll:**

```
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult Custom5(Session session)
    {            
        session["LVAL"] = "1";
        MessageBox.Show("LVAL :" + session["LVAL"]);
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

When I try to show value of `LVAL` at exit dialog, I see its value as "0". So I can't see the value which was set inside custom action. Any advice or solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Custom actions that set/get public installer properties must be set to run as **Immediate**. Deferred custom actions cannot get/set these properties. Check that yours is set as immediate.

Also, here is how to [attach and debug the code from your custom action](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-c-sharp-ca.html).